# Getting HTTP response code in AsyncTask Android take to long

Tags: android, http, webview, android-asynctask, httpresponse

I developing Android app which base on WebView, i need to check if http status code of web that i want to load  is < 400 (if there is an error) before i display my page.

```
Web View code:
   @Override
            public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
                super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);

                    GetHTTPStatus task = new GetHTTPStatus(thisActivity);
                    task.execute(url);
                    httpError = false;

            }
```

Code of getting status code:

```
 // Below code is parto of:static class GetHTTPStatus extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Integer> {

                HttpClient httpClient;
                HttpParams params1 = new BasicHttpParams();
                params1.setParameter(CoreProtocolPNames.PROTOCOL_VERSION,HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1);
                httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(params1);
                HttpPost post = new HttpPost(RequestedURL);
                HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(post);
                int code = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
                listener.OnHTTPRespone(code);
```

then i rise up proper action (in this case displaying Dialog with proper message) by implementing my interface and overriding:

```
 @Override
    public int OnHTTPRespone(int httpMessage) {
// if httpMessage > 400 display message code
}
```

Problem is that web view is displaying bad url faster than my dialog box. 
in other words **checking of response code is to slow** i need to speed it up a bit. 
I know that i can not displaying view of my web page until OnHTTPRespone is rise but then whole app become not very user friendly.

Comment: In addition i can add that onReceivedError in webview does not catch HTTP errors (only content errors)

Comment: Is not downloading the whole page but only the headers an option?

Comment: I did it on purpose to speed up (i need only to know if the page is available) But is still to slow.